# how to handle communicate with couple of different urls with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, design-patterns, networking, afnetworking

For my app, I need to communicate with many different urls in the same app, I want to handle this requirements with `AFNetworking` API, but the `AFNetworking` examples used a singleton to communicate with one base url, and put the http requests with different relative urls in the operation queue. I am still puzzled with the design using `AFNetworking`, I think I need to create a couple of singletons to handle different urls, that's definitely a weired design, or I need to re-write the `AFHTTPClient` to fit my requirements, or I need a networkingMgr to maintain a list of `AFHTTPClient`, it's hard to decouple the `AFHTTPClient` with different urls. Could anybody give some suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by communicate? you can communicate with multiple urls using AFNetworking - Im sure Ive performed multiple GET requests in a single app before.

Comment: for communication I mean, send get, post request, you perform multiple GET request using same baseURL and different relative URL or different base URL?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you can't use the following code taken from: [CocoaDocs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.1.0/)

Using you own NSString for the URL

```
 NSString *myUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseUrl,relativeUrl];

 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:myUrlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```